# Hash links to hard links when Javascript disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, hyperlink

Hi this is the code I have and it works.

```
function Init(){
 ShowPage ('#body_home');
}

function ShowPage(a){
 $(a).css("display","block");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(e){
     $(".page").fadeOut(1000).delay(1500);  
     $("#" + $(this).data("page")).fadeIn(1000);
  });        
});
```

Basically I want to know how to make the links point to their correct pages if the user has javascript disabled. Is this possible? I'm currently using a hash link system. I want so if the user has javascript disabled that the links will work (e.g. index.php instead of #body_home) without using a second stylesheet.

HTML

```
<ul class="navlist">
<li class="litem" name="home"><a data-page="body_home" href="#body_home">Home</a></li>
<li class="litem" name="hello"><a data-page="body_hello" href="#body_hello">Hello</a></li>
```

Comment: not if you only have javascript code! pls provide your html that you already tried!

Answer (score 0):

Just give you links a `href` attribute.

```
<a href="index.php>Link</a>
```

And include `return false;` in your `click()` handler:

(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(e){
     $(".page").fadeOut(1000).delay(1500);
     $("#" + $(this).data("page")).fadeIn(1000);
     e.preventDefault(); 
     return false;
  });
});

You may also need `e.prevenDefault();` (included above), not sure about that though.

Comment: And prevent default on it. If js is disabled, the javascript to prevent the link's execution won't fire, and if it is enabled, your regular click handling can happen

Comment: This won't work because the way the jquery is setup with the html. please read the updated question for further information.